# Crystal Report Deployment

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, report

I have a VB.Net winforms application that it includes all the DLL in its BIN folder, i deploy it to the client's server everything works good without installing anything on each workstation.. i take a shortcut from the server..

the problem is when i try from any station to preview a crystal report file even tho i installed the runtimes on the server where the shortcut is located but it doesnt work without installing the runtime on each workstation 
Any idea how to reference or load crystal report runtime from where the shortcut is located?

Comment: It is the users computer the one that gets the report file and visualizes it, so it needs the runtime in the users computer. You could consider a server based solution like Crystal Server, but I can not give much detail because I have never used it.

Comment: i cannot find any tutorials regarding this.. :/

Comment: Careful, asking about tutorials is offtopic, usually more concrete questions are wanted. As a personal preference I deeply dislike Crystal Reports, if it is not a fixed requirement I would suggest you checking other alternatives (SQL Server has pretty nice reporting services)

Comment: What i meant is crystal report server will not help me in my case.. and it s unfortunately a fixed requirements because we have over 400 reports..